# Android - Programatically changing Popup Window's layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `PopupWindow` which finally decides to follow my command and show itself after null error(certainly not my mistake in forgetting to initialize some value).

Here's the xml file for the `PopupWindow`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_Wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/popupkodehp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:text="@string/popupPhoneMessage"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_functionalities"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/popup_handphone_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_phoneNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Phone Number"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColor" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/popup_handphone_phoneNumberConfirm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/popup_handphone_phoneNumber"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="Retype Phone Number"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/popup_handphone_phoneNumberConfirm"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:minHeight="20dp"
                android:text="Send Code"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the code of the `PopupWindow` I made with the help of anonymous and amazing people all over Google

```
View.OnClickListener phoneReinputHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            /*Intent intent = new Intent(SignupStepTwoActivity.this, PopupHandphone.class);
            backDim = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bac_dim_layout);
            //backDim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startActivity(intent);*/

            mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_two_mainLayout);

            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
/*            View popupLayoutInflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_handphone, mainLayout);

            RelativeLayout popupFunctionalitiesWrapper = (RelativeLayout)popupLayoutInflater.findViewById(R.id.popup_handphone_functionalities);
            int popupFunctionalitiesWrapperHeight = layoutResize.height(70, displayMetrics);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams popupFunctionalitiesWrapperParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)popupFunctionalitiesWrapper.getLayoutParams();
            popupFunctionalitiesWrapperParams.height = popupFunctionalitiesWrapperHeight;
*/
            PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_handphone, null, false),
                    (int)(width * .8),
                    (int)(height*.35),
                    true);
            pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
            pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);

            pw.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        }
    };
```

The second commented part is a failed attempt to set the layout element's height. It shows itself on the main layout too, as in, the whole `PopupWindow` layout lay on top of the class' layout.

How to programatically customize the `PopupWindow` layout I made from the class' layout I'm at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer on how to change the insides of the `PopupWindow` using `popupWindow.getContentView()`

As usual, instantiate the `PopupWindow`

```
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_handphone, null, false),
                    (int)(width * .8),
                    (int)(height*.35),
                    true);
```

THEN call the layout of the `PopupWindow` using..

```
RelativeLayout popupFunctionalitiesWrapper = (RelativeLayout)pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popup_handphone_functionalities);
```

Notice that `pw.getContentView()` is there before `findViewById`.

And thru that `popupFunctionalitiesWrapper`, I can set stuffs like..

```
int popupFunctionalitiesWrapperWidth = layoutResize.width(70);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams popupFunctionalitiesWrapperParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)popupFunctionalitiesWrapper.getLayoutParams();
            popupFunctionalitiesWrapperParams.width = popupFunctionalitiesWrapperWidth;
            popupFunctionalitiesWrapperParams.addRule(Gravity.CENTER);
            popupFunctionalitiesWrapper.setLayoutParams(popupFunctionalitiesWrapperParams);
```

Yeah and that's that!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the `PopupWindow` width and height while the popupwindow is showing then use the function `PopupWindow.update`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that for the window itself? Or it can be used for individual component inside??

Comment: If you want to reset the `width` and `height` then `PopupWindow` object or if you want to update the individual component inside then get the view from popupwindow by `PopupWindow.getContentView` and then update